# How to handle no records found in angular datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using `angular-datatables` in my app. I don't know how to handle when ajax source returns empty array. I am expecting to show some message to indicate "No Records found".

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {         
     dataSrc: 'data',
     url: 'api_url',
     type: 'GET'
 })    
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');


$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
];
```

My Ajax response is as below

```
{"status":false,"message":"No data were found","data":[]}
```

So how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a [**`language`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) struct with the desired messages. The key you are looking for is called `zeroRecords`. Small example :

```
$scope.language = {
   "zeroRecords": "No records found",
}

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
   .withOption('ajax', {         
       dataSrc: 'data',
       url: 'api_url',
       type: 'GET'
   })    
   .withPaginationType('full_numbers') 
   .withOption('language', $scope.language)
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/teJbmQA3wEnzvKEi63IL?p=preview**

---

To catch 404, simply set up an error handler :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {         
    dataSrc: 'data',
    url: 'api_url',
    type: 'GET',
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      if (xhr.status==404) {
        //no specific action needed
      }
   }  
})
```

By that you will avoid the ugly dataTables warning alert box telling the user there has been an ajax error. The `zeroRecords` message will still be showed.

Comment: I understand the problem. I was setting 404 header when I return empty data response. If I changed to 200 status header from api it's seems setting default message "No data available in table". But it's useful answer, is there way to handle 404 response header.

Comment: Is there a way to use "No data were found" from the json source?

Comment: @Gowri, no - the `language` option is bind to dataTables once, it is not a dynamic value. You could perhaps make a dirty "hack" where you create a row containing the error message if `data` is empty.

Comment: Error handler compressed the error alert, but data table always shows "processing".  Dynamic error message should be useful one. Unfortunately it's not there.

Comment: @Gowri, do you have everything in place? It works here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/UOGYN1oea2adyZQ2bnAk?p=preview** both suppressing the alert and showing a custom zeroRecord message ...

Comment: oh my mistake, I was commented the language option, Thanks for the great help here